# Reject or retain the null hypotheses with insufficient data

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I stated a number of hypotheses and conducted a questionnaire. Only after the questionnaire it appeared I skrewed up with the questions. These questions don't actually allow me do reject or retain the set hypotheses. So my question is what do I do? Do I reject or retain?

Comment: Are you saying that the questions on your questionnaire are unrelated to your hypothesis? Can you provide more detail?

Comment: @gung  
For example, my hypotheses states: "If the costs of copyrighted content are lowered the individual’s intent to commit piracy will not decrease". But what the questionnaire actually measured was the effect of the costs on the individual's intent to buy. As you can see I can't use this questionnaire to answer my hypotheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have sufficient evidence to reject a null, you fail to reject it.

When your data doesn't speak to it at all, it remains unrejected.